# Check constraint on a column or table that occurs on insert update and delete?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there anyway to add a check constraint on a column or table that occurs on insert update and delete? Could a trigger be used instead of a check constraint?

I have a project members table with columns project user and owner. Each project must have at least one owner. So in the example below projects 1 and 2 are valid and project 3 is invalid.

Additionally deletion of the record project = 1 and user = 1 should not be allowed because the project 1 would no longer have an owner.

```
|Project|User|Owner|
|1      |1   |Yes  |
|1      |2   |No   |
|2      |3   |No   |
|2      |4   |Yes  |
|3      |3   |No   |
|3      |2   |No   |
```

Comment: yes,you can use after update/delete trigger for your case here.I also recommend adding generalized tag like sqlserver for more visibilty going forward

Comment: How do you propose to insert new items into the Project table? They would instantly violate this rule? Maybe you could introduce the idea of a PrimaryOwnerId and have that as a not nullable column in Project.

Comment: When a project is create a project member record is create with the user column set to the logged in user and the owner column set to Yes